# Storing the results from a function into a retrievable DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and just been through a couple of books and tutorials on data analysis/ machine learning.

I want to build a classifer and trying to scrape real time stock data.

The following function to pull real time data

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests

def get_intraday_data(symbol, interval_seconds=301, num_days=10):
    # Specify URL string based on function inputs.
    url_string = 'http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=   {0}'.format(symbol.upper())
    url_string += "&i={0}&p={1}d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v".format(interval_seconds,num_days)

    # Request the text, and split by each line
    r = requests.get(url_string).text.split()

    # Split each line by a comma, starting at the 8th line
    r = [line.split(',') for line in r[7:]]

    # Save data in Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=    ['Datetime','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume'])

    # Convert UNIX to Datetime format
    df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[1:])))

    return df
```

When I try to call df, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-db884686c2f6> in <module>()
     18     return df
     19 
---> 20 symbol = pd.DataFrame(df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

The issue is that I want to be able to store this into a seperate date frame and call it later. The function appears to runs and not store it anywhere. I will appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: I have tried this. Didnt address my problem as I still get the error saying df is not a defined function after adding a procedure to store the results in HDFS @user2539738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with computer science terminology to thoroughly explain this to you, but basically, when you call a function that has a return value, that value must be saved as a variable.

df only exists in your function.  (I think that's called scope).  When you leave the function, df is gone

You're doing

```
get_intraday_data(symbol, 301,10)
```

So, after that function is run, the returned variable is gone

instead, do the following:

```
df = get_intraday_data(symbol, 301,10)
```

then you can do stuff with it

Alternatively, instead of returning the df, you can pickle it.  In your "get_intraday_symbol"

```
fname = 'file1.P'
df.to_pickle(fname)
return fname
```

Then, subsequent code has to read the pickled dataframe

```
fname = get_intraday_data(symbol, 301,10)
df = pd.read_pickle(fname)
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks!!